# How to access field data in other field

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

I have a modal form with a form that uses `Formik`. Here are two pictures that show two states of that form that can be toggled with a switch.Initially I fill text into fields which can be added dynamically and stored as an array with .
The second picture shows how I toggled to `textarea`. There you can also add text with commas that will be turned into an array.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to fill data in input fields from the first screen, toggle into `textarea` and access already inputted data.

I understand formik keeps that state somewhere. But at the moment these fields have a separate state. 
Here is my component:

```js
class ModalForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      disabled: true,
    };
  }

  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      disabled: !this.state.disabled,
    });
  };

  render() {
    var {
      visible = false,
      onCancel,
      onRequest,
      submitting,
      setSubscriberType,
      editing,
      subscriptionTypeString,
      tested,
      selectedGates,
    } = this.props;
    const { gateId } = selectedGates.length && selectedGates[0];
    const handleSubmit = values => {
      console.log(values);
      onRequest && onRequest({ gateId, ...values });
    };
    const { disabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <Modal
        footer={null}
        closable
        title="Список абонентов для выбранного гейта"
        visible={visible}
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onOk={handleSubmit}
        destroyOnClose
        width="600px"
      >
        <StyledDescription>
          <Switch onChange={this.onChange} />
          <StyledLabel>массовый ввод</StyledLabel>
        </StyledDescription>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ abonents: [''] }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          render={({ values, handleChange }) => (
            <Form>
              {disabled ? (
                <FieldArray
                  name="abonents"
                  render={arrayHelpers => {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {values.abonents.map((value, index) => (
                          <div key={index}>
                            <MyTextInput
                              placeholder="Абонент ID"
                              name={`abonents.${index}`}
                              value={value}
                              onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <Button
                              shape="circle"
                              icon="delete"
                              onClick={() => {
                                arrayHelpers.remove(index);
                              }}
                            />
                          </div>
                        ))}

                        <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}>
                          <Icon type="plus" />Добавить абонента
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }}
                />
              ) : (
                <StyledField
                  placeholder="Введите ID абонентов через запятую"
                  name="message"
                  component="textarea"
                />
              )}

              <Footer>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                  Запросить
                </Button>
              </Footer>
            </Form>
          )}
        />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy, formik stores values inside `values.abonents`, hence you can use it inside textarea

```js
let { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage, FieldArray }  = window.Formik;
function App () {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false) // some boilerplate code
  function submit (values) {
    console.log('submit', values)
  }
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ abonents: [] }}
      onSubmit={submit}
      render={({ values, handleChange, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name='abonents'
            render={arrayHelpers => {
              if (!disabled) {
                return (
                  <textarea onChange={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    setFieldValue('abonents', e.target.value.split(', '))
                  }} value={values.abonents.join(', ')}></textarea>
                )
              }
              return (
                <div>
                  {
                    values.abonents.map((value, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <input
                          placeholder='Абонент ID'
                          name={`abonents.${index}`}
                          value={value}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <button onClick={(e) => {
                          e.preventDefault()
                          arrayHelpers.remove(index)
                        }}>
                          -
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    ))
                  }

                  <button onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    arrayHelpers.push('')
                  }}>
                    +
                  </button>
                </div>
              )
            }}
          />
          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
          <button onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setDisabled(!disabled)
          }}>toggle</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.9.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/formik/dist/formik.umd.production.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You have got to give the same name to the input and textarea, so whe you add text in input will automatically change text in textarea

```js
                         <FieldArray
              name="abonents"
              render={arrayHelpers => {
```

and

```js
               <StyledField
                  placeholder="Введите ID абонентов через запятую"
                  name="abonents"
                  component="textarea"
                />
```

These two fields have same name so they are rendered interchangeably but have common text inside them

Comment: this is wrong, textarea expects string value, fieldarray expects array value